# Unable to Install Torch or torch vision in pycharm I am running python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pytorch

Installing torch from PyCharm interpreter but error occurs. Python 3.6

```
Collecting torch==0.4.1.post2

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.4.1.post2 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch==0.4.1.post2
```

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing lower version of torch, go to:

> File->Setting->Project[project_name]-> Project Interpreter -> + ->
>   search for torch, in right lower corner is check box 'Specify version'

check it and try sevral starting from top. From what i see current is 1.2.0